# How can i fix the error on the DispatchGroup leave in swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, realm

I want to load all data from firebase, then show the data to the table view. But now, I can't show all the data to the table view. It is because call the finishLoading(realm) method is faster than the for loop get all the data. How can I do some show all data when for loop is finish in swift. I have to use the Closure, however the second of the loop is later than this "self.finishLoading(realm: realm)"

I have to try to add the DispatchGroup(), however, the leave() when having an error of EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION. Can I put the leave() in the closure? How can I fix it?

```
  func loopAllProduct(userId: String, finishLoadWhenErr:Bool, storedClosure: @escaping (DocumentSnapshot) -> Void){
        let storage = Storage.storage()
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        let userDocRef = db.collection("Users").document(userId).collection("Product")
        userDocRef.getDocuments{(document, error) in
            if let err = error {
                print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
            } else {
                for document in document!.documents {
                    storedClosure(document)
                }
            }
        }

    }
    func downloadData() {
        let startTime = Date()
        while updating {
            let diffTime = Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: startTime.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate)
            if (diffTime.timeIntervalSinceNow < -5){
                self.stopAnimating()
                self.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
                print("Update Timeout")
                return
            }
        }
        updating = true
        let storage = Storage.storage()
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        let productLoading = NSMutableArray()
        let realm = try! Realm()
        print("all posts")
        let group = DispatchGroup()
        let addPosts: (DocumentSnapshot)->Void = {(document) in
                try! realm.write {
                    if let resuls = self.realmResults {
                        realm.delete(resuls);
                    }
                }

                let product = Product()
                product.id = document.documentID
                product.userID = document.data()?["UserID"] as? String
                product.userName = document.data()?["UserName"] as? String
                product.descrition = document.data()?["Descrition"] as? String
                product.postTime = document.data()?["PostTime"] as? Date
                product.price = document.data()?["Price"] as? Double ?? 0.0
                product.stat = (document.data()?["stat"] as? Int)!
                product.productName = document.data()?["ProductName"] as? String
                let productId = document.documentID
                productLoading.add(productId)
                try! realm.write {
                    realm.add(product)
                }
             group.leave()
        }
        let userDocRef = db.collection("Users")
        userDocRef.getDocuments{(document, error) in
        for document in document!.documents {
                group.enter()
                self.loopAllProduct(userId:document.documentID , finishLoadWhenErr: true, storedClosure: addPosts)
            }
        }
        group.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
            self.finishLoading(realm: realm)
         }
    }
```

Comment: You need to `enter` the group before you call `getDocuments` otherwise the `notify` will fire immediately. Assuming that `updating` is initially `false` your `while` loop will be skipped. If `updating` is false, it will block the main thread for 5 seconds (which is bad)

Comment: The question is a bit vague and you may be running into an asynchronous issue with Realm and Firebase. I see this `self.loopAllProduct(use` is being called within a tight loop and directly following that you have a `group.notify(queue:` which will be called before Firebase can return the data. You should set up your code to only work with data returned from Firebase *within the closure* and not expect code following the closure to execute first. Additionally, you've implementing DispatchQueue which are often unneeded as Firebase closure calls (except UI) execute in the background.

Comment: What happened to your earlier version of this question? You asked the question, you were given extensive help by @vadian, then you deleted that question and you now use his code without credit and you ask about it as a new question?